# Google SEO - duplicate content in web pages for submitting sitemaps

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I hope my question is not too irrelevant to stackoverflow.

this is my website: http://www.rader.my

It's a car information website. The content is dynamic. Therefore, google crawler could not find all the cars specification pages in my website.

I created a sitemap with all my cars URL in it (for instance: http://www.rader.my/Details.php?ID=13 is for one car). I know I haven't made any mistake in my .xml file format and structure. But after submission, google only indexed one URL which is my index.php.

I have also read about `rel="canonical"`. But I don't think in my case I should use such a thing since all my pages ARE different with different content but only the structure is the same.

Is there anything that I missed? Why google doesn't accept my URLs even though the contents are different? What can I do to fix this?

Thanks and regards,

Amin

Comment: You mentioned you made a sitemap, yet I cant see it at the usual address.  What is the address of the sitemap.xml file, and have you submitted it in Google Webmaster Tools?

Comment: Here is the address: http://www.rader.my/Sitemaps/baseSitemap.xml And yes I have submitted these sitemaps in `/Sitemaps` directory in Google Webmaster Tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar type of site.  Google is good about figuring out dynamic sites.  They'll crawl the pages and figure out the unique content as time goes on.  Give it time.

You should do all the standard things:

1. Make sure each page has a unique H1 tag.
2. Make sure each page has substantial unique content
3. Unique keywords and description tags aren't as useful as they used to be but they can't hurt.
4. Cross-link internally.  Create category pages that include links to all of one manufacturer and have each of the pages of that manufacturer link back to 'similar' pages.
5. Get links to your pages.  Nothing helps getting indexed like external authority.

Comment: wow, thanks! I had no idea about these standard rules until now. Are these rules approved by google as well? Where can I find an article or something about these rules?

Comment: As for substantial unique content, each page is for one car's specification, do you think it's not enough and I should add more unique content to it?

Comment: You should be fine. My car site that follows these rules has five million indexed pages in Google.

Comment: So according to your standard rules, the unique H1 tag is the only thing I'm missing. I'll give it a try and come back to you after changes. Again thanks for the help mate.